# What is the meaning of = and === when used in one line or in one variable?

Tags: php

I saw a code showing below.

```
$selected_value = 'yes' === ( isset( $option['default'] ) ? $option['default'] : 'no' );
```

I know the difference between = and === and the way how they are used above is new to me. Can someone explain?

Comment: It's assigning (`=`) the result of an equality comparison (`===`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$option['default']` contains "yes" then `$selected_value` is set to `true`, otherwise (if it contains something else, or does not exist) it is set to `false`.

The ternary clause ( condition? true-return-value : false-return-value) either returns "no", or the contents of `$option['default']`. If that return is equal to `yes`, then the result of the `===` comparison will be `true`, otherwise it will be `false`.

Comment: Ok, so do you mean this, if the result of ( isset( $option['default'] ) ? $option['default'] : 'no' ) is 'yes', then it would be $selected_value = 'yes' === 'yes' where the final value assign to $selected_value is 'yes'. And if  $selected_value = 'yes' === 'no', then the final value is 'no'. Am I right?

Comment: Not quite. The outer condition is to see whether the string "yes" is equal (both in content and type) to the result of the ternary operator. So if the ternary operator returns "yes" (which it only does if that option string exists and is set to "yes"), the result will be a boolean "true", otherwise it will be a boolean "false". `echo 'yes' === 'yes'` to test.

Comment: Meaning that if $selected_value = 'yes' === 'yes' then the final value assign to $selected_value is true. And if $selected_value = 'yes' === 'no', then the final value is false. Correct?

Comment: Exactly that, yes.